# Update multiple rows of same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table `Employee` with following Sample Data

```
ID   Name   Gender
1    Mary   F
2    John   M
3    Smith  M
```

I want to write an Update query that would set Gender to `F` where Gender is `M` and set Gender to `M` where Gender is `F`. How can I do this in single `update` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply use `case`:

```
update t
    set Gender = (case when Gender = 'F' then 'M' else 'F' end)
    where Gender in ('F', 'M');
```

Answer (score 1):

We can update by using `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
update Employee 
set Gender = (
    case Gender when 'M' then 'F'
    when 'F' then 'M' 
    else Gender end
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when to update

```
update employee set Gender=(case when Gender='F' then 'M' else 'f' end)
where gender in ('M','F')
```